# PHP Memcached issue

Tags: php, memcached

How to set the two different memcache for two different PHP application in One server(windows and linux)

I know how to set for single application.But i am not able to configure for two different PHP application. So please guide me anyone who is good in memcached.

Answer (score 2):

You can use different ports, for example:

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('memcache_host', 11211);

$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('memcache_host', 11212);
```

And run memcached using different ports, like this (for linux):

```
memcached -p 11211 -d
memcached -p 11212 -d
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Different ports, good solution. But IMO `Memcached` is better (use `Memcached::addServers(Array)`): http://us2.php.net/manual/en/memcached.addservers.php

Comment: Do We need to do any additional settings in php.ini file.

Comment: No, only enable memchache extension.

Comment: Thanks! Dan & krayton i will check and if any issues comes add it again in the conversation

Comment: Btw, if you don't wana run several memcached instances, you can just use different keys prefixes for your applications.